# elasticsearch not responding to bulk operation

Tags: java, azure, elasticsearch, bulkinsert

I have 3 master node + 3 data nodes elasticsearch cluster on azure. I am trying to execute bulk operation but I get failed error about the nodes itself, here is how I setup my client:

```
    final Builder builder = Settings.builder();
    final org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.Builder transBuilder = TransportClient.builder();
    builder.put("cluster.name", esCluster);
    if (esShield) {
        builder.put("shield.user", esUsername + ":" + esPassword);
        transBuilder.addPlugin(ShieldPlugin.class);
    }
    final Settings settings = builder.build();
    TransportClient esClient = transBuilder.settings(settings).build();
    final String[] hosts = esHost.split(",");
    for (String host : hosts) {
        esClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host, Integer.parseInt(esPort))));
    }
```

here is the bulk operation:

```
BulkProcessor bulkProcessor = BulkProcessor.builder(getClient(), new BulkProcessor.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void beforeBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request) {
            LOGGER.info("Going to execute new bulk composed of {" + request.numberOfActions() + "} actions");
        }

        @Override
        public void afterBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request, BulkResponse response) {
            LOGGER.info("Executed bulk composed of {" + request.numberOfActions() + "} actions");
        }

        @Override
        public void afterBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request, Throwable failure) {
            LOGGER.info("Error executing bulk");
            failure.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).setBulkActions(docs.size()).setConcurrentRequests(250).build();
    for (DBObject doc : docs) {
        bulkProcessor.add(getClient().prepareIndex(indexName, typeName).setSource(doc.toMap()).request());
    }
```

It starts responding fine for a 1,000 record batches like this:

> Going to execute new bulk composed of {1001} actions
>
> Executed bulk composed of {1001} actions

Then I started getting the following error:

> transport:383 - [Stanley Stewart] failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}{10.0.0.10}{10.0.0.10:9300}, disconnecting...
>   ReceiveTimeoutTransportException[[][10.0.0.10:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness] request_id [60] timed out after [5000ms]]
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:679)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Finally I got the following error:

> bulk:148 - [Stanley Stewart] Failed to execute bulk request 1.
>   NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{10.0.0.10}{10.0.0.10:9300}, {#transport#-2}{10.0.0.11}{10.0.0.11:9300}, {#transport#-3}{10.0.0.12}{10.0.0.12:9300}]]
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:290)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:207)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:288)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:359)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.bulk(AbstractClient.java:436)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.Retry$AbstractRetryHandler.execute(Retry.java:219)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.Retry.withAsyncBackoff(Retry.java:72)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequestHandler$AsyncBulkRequestHandler.execute(BulkRequestHandler.java:121)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.execute(BulkProcessor.java:312)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.executeIfNeeded(BulkProcessor.java:303)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.internalAdd(BulkProcessor.java:285)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.add(BulkProcessor.java:268)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.add(BulkProcessor.java:264)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.add(BulkProcessor.java:250)

Can someone help me please figure out whats going on and how to fix it?

Comment: From my experience bulk operation is quite fragile in ES. I don't know about Azure but with my on premise installation I have provided ES with as much memory I can. Then I experimented with size of a single bulk and time breaks between bulks. In your situation try to lower the bulk to say 100 docs and introduce time breaks say 1s. Experiment with it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the refresh interval of index it too low. Try setting refresh interval of index to -1 before bulk process. you can reset it once bulk process is completed.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#bulk